# rich:panelBarItem is not displaying its contents when used in a4j:repeat or ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client">
   <rich:tab label="Display">
        <h:form id="displayForm">
            <rich:panelBar height="400" width="500" id="displayPanel" >
                <ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.myMap}" var="item">
                    <rich:panelBarItem label="#{item.key.name}">

                     Ajax4jsf is fully integrated into the JSF lifecycle. While other frameworks only give you access to the managed bean facility, Ajax4jsf advantages the action and value change listeners as well as invokes server-side validators and converters during the AJAX request-response cycle.

                   </rich:panelBarItem>
                </ui:repeat>
        </rich:panelBar>
     </h:form>
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

Hi, using above code I want to display multiple panelBarItems(number depends on the no of name values present in database). I am able to view the panelBarItems in UI  but the problem is inside content(Ajax4jsf is..)  is not visible and when clicked on other panelBarItems it is not expanding. Can we use ui:repeat or a4j:repeat with rich:panelBarItem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ui:repeat` you can use `c:forEach` tag. Then `rich:panelBarItem` is working without any issues.

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client">
   <rich:tab label="Display">
    <h:form id="displayForm">
        <rich:panelBar height="400" width="500" id="displayPanel" >
            <c:forEach value="#{backingBean.myMap}" var="item">
                <rich:panelBarItem label="#{item.key.name}">

                 Ajax4jsf is fully integrated into the JSF lifecycle. While other frameworks only give you access to the managed bean facility, Ajax4jsf advantages the action and value change listeners as well as invokes server-side validators and converters during the AJAX request-response cycle.

               </rich:panelBarItem>
            </c:forEach>
    </rich:panelBar>
 </h:form>
</rich:tab>
```